# How to call pages dynamically play scala using Intellij idea

Tags: html, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I have uploaded a simple web template in play Scala using intellij idea. how to call each section from different file, 
  I am calling each function from index.scala.html
     this is my main.scala.html

```
    <html>
    <body  id="page-top" class="index">
       @navigation
          @header
             @services
                  @portfolio
                         @about
                         @team
                  @client
             @contact
          @footer
 </body>
 </html>
```

As the above code how to have each function that is `@services` in separate file, `@portfolio` in separate file .
      this is my index.scala.html

```
  @(message: String)

   @navigation = { navigation html code}

     @header = {<header> html code</header>}
      @services = {

       <section id="services"><!--html code for reference-->
        <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>

          </div>
         </div>
       <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">E-Commerce</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">Responsive Design</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
             </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">Web Security</h4>

        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     </section>

    }
@main("hello test")(navigation)(header)(services){  }
```

my application package controllers

```
  import play.api._
  import play.api.mvc._

  object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Ok"))
      }
   }
```

my routes

```
   GET        /                    controllers.Application.index
```

I wanted header to be in same file ., make @services @portfolio into different different files and call them as one page web page dynamically.

Comment: Find in target index.template.scala. You will see that functions navigation, header and other are declared inside object index apply method. So there are inaccessible (even by reflection). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know one solution. You have to create one file per function.

navigation.scala.html

```
@()
navigation html code
```

header.scala.html

```
@()
<header> html code</header>
```

And other.
You can create it in separate package/folder (mainscala) and import all files:

```
@import views.html.mainscala._
```

And add brackets:

```
<html>
    <body  id="page-top" class="index">
       @navigation()
          @header()
....
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you meant each function in each file . in href how do i give the link  and where do i use  @import views.html.mainscala._

Comment: `@import views.html.mainscala._` use only if you create mainscala package (add before using, but after first statement `@(...)`). If not, just call `@main("hello test")(navigation())(header())(services()){  }` in index.scala.html